# Using matlab matrix as input for a python code

Tags: python, matlab

Is it possible to use a matrix generated with matlab and saved in a binary file as input of a python script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it's possible.  bits are bits, you just need to know how to interpret them :).  Fortunately for you, it looks like someone has already done the hard work of figuring out the matlab file format and has written a reader for it ... Have a look at the [scipy.io](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html) module.  Specifically, the `loadmat` function might be useful.

`scipy` isn't in the python standard library, but generally speaking, if you're going to be trying to use python to replicate something done in matlab, you'll probably want to have it and it's sibling/child package `numpy` installed.

Comment: As an aside: there's no need to "figure out" the matlab file format. It's public :) http://www.mathworks.com/help/pdf_doc/matlab/matfile_format.pdf